# How limit the transform position in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to way to limit the transform position in Y axis of my object. To moving I'm using that code

```
transform.position += Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * speed;
```

Object is moving only when player is holding the button, after that the object is going back to 1st position. How can I block the moving for example from 6 to -6 in Y axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `transform.position` and `Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * speed` both have (x, y, z) as they are `Vector3` you could simply check the Y component and skip the movement between the specified range, e.g.

```
if(transform.position.y < -6 || transform.position.y > 6)
{
    // the Vector3.down is (0, -1, 0) so this operation will change only Y component anyway
    transform.position += Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * speed;
}
```

---

In the original OP overshoot has not been mentioned but as @derHugo pointed out you could limit move to avoid overshoot. One possibility is like this, it will limit the move regarding the nearest border, preventing also to jump from one border to another...

```
private static float OutsideLimitedMove(float current, float move, float bottomLimit, float topLimit)
{
    //----->---------|  not allowed  |---------<-----
    // fromBottom   -6               6       fromUp 

    if(current >= -6 && current <= 6) 
        return 0f;

    float predictedY = current + move;

    //fromBottom
    if(current < bottomLimit && predictedY > bottomLimit) 
        return Math.Min(bottomLimit - current, move);

    //fromUp
    if (current > topLimit && predictedY < topLimit)
        return Math.Max(topLimit - current, move);

    return move;
}

Vector3 predictedMove = Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * speed;
float y = OutsideLimitedMove(transform.position.y, predictedMove.y, -6, 6);
transform.position += new Vector3(predictedMove.x, y, predictedMove.z);
```

Comment: This does not limit exactly to `-6` and `6` but allows overshooting depending on the `speed`. It also does not allow any future movement once one limit is reached for moving the object back e.g. (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55882342/7111561))

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question you want the object being limited to stay between -6 and 6.

You can e.g. use [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) to limit `position.y` like

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,      
                                 Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y + Time.deltaTime * speed, -6.0f, 6.0f), 
                                 transform.position.z);
```

In contrary to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55882186/7111561) this limits the movement exactly to the given values and prevents any overshooting. It also would still allow to move the object back once one limit is reached while the other answer ignores any future movement once a limit is reached.

Comment: As you pointed in your comment to see your answer I am looking at it :). You are limiting the move itself to be [-6,6] but OP asks how to block the movement of the object within that range, not the move itself.

Comment: Now you adopted your post .. but only way more complicated than what I proposed here ^^ limiting the position to exactly the range is exactly the same as your "blocking" the movement ;) with the difference as said that my version still allows to move the object back ... your solution in contrary will ignore any further input once one of the limits is reached.

Comment: `Mathf.Clamp` will clamp the number within the range so you allow only move between [-6,6] but OP asks how to block the move between [-6,6] not sure if I understand you...

Comment: Well maybe I understand the question wrong but to me it sounds like the goal is that the object can only move between -6 and 6.